# MS Edge: form submitted even if return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I got a strange problem when creating a login form for a website I create for work. I know it has been posed a million times but my case only breaks in Edge.

Principle is: I have a form with username and password. When submitting the form user and pass is validated and logged in in ajax (and returns error if so). If valid it redirects to the main user. (simple, no?)

Problem is that the page is refreshed anyway even if the form have `return: false`, **but only in Microsoft Edge**. It works on Chrome, IE (even in document mode 10) and Firefox with no problems.

Code in action:

```
<!-- jQuery + validate plugins are already loaded -->  
<form id="loginform" method="post" class="">
    <div class="navbar-login panel">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">Connexion au cours</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="login-warning"></div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <input class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" placeholder="Adresse email" name="LOGIN_EMAIL" type="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <input class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" placeholder="Mot de passe" name="LOGIN_PASSWORD" type="password">                      
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="panel-heading text-right" style="display: table;width: 100%;">
            <button type="submit" style="float: right;display: inline-block;" class="btn btn-info">Connexion</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$("#loginform").validate({
    debug: false,
    rules: {
        LOGIN_EMAIL: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        LOGIN_PASSWORD: {
            minlength: 6
        }
    }
});
$("#loginform").submit(function(e){
    var f = $(this);
    if(f.valid()){
        $.ajax({
            url: "req/ajx_login.php",
            type:"POST",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            data: f.serialize(),
            success: function(data, status, xhr){
                // data is "success" if successed, anything else if failed
                if(data == "success"){
                    location = "/cours";
                }else{
                    $("#login-warning").html(data);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Can someone help? Thanks for future answers.

Comment: Any luck when you add the *event* parameter and call `preventDefault` on it? `submit(function( event ) {  ....  event.preventDefault(); })`

Comment: Nope, already tested :(

Comment: Do you see any errors in console? Note that if an exception occurs in the submit handler, the `return false` will not be reached. You could maybe add some `console.log` just before the `return false` and check if it gets executed.

Comment: No errors. But I've another form submitted via ajax in the same page and this one works (with a really similar code)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am experiencing the exact same problem. Every other browser works except edge.